# Utilizar JNA para acceder a una funcion de una DLL (C#) desde Java?

Tags: java

Tengo una `DLL` (`TransferImg.dll`) que está escrita en `C#` (proporcionada por una empresa externa), la cual me comentan que necesito crear una interfaz para acceder a funciones de transmisión de imágenes desde JAVA, estuve investigando de como, pero no he encontrado algo que entienda o me funcione.

Los datos que me proporcionaron son: 
-  Librería TransferImg.dll
-  Agregar referencia a proyecto.
-  Agregar `Using Transfer`;
-  Crear Objeto `Command myobj = new Command();`
-  Llamar a la función `myobj.SendImagesToScale`la cual retorna un entero con el error.

Esta es la función que deseo utilizar:

```
int SendImagesToScale(string Ip, string PathImage ,string Tipo, Socket iSock);
```

No tengo una idea clara de como hacerlo, este es mi código tomado de un ejemplo:

```
public class SendImg {
    public interface CLibrary extends Library {
        CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary)
            Native.loadLibrary((Platform.isWindows() ? "C:\TransferImg.dll" : "c#"),                                   CLibrary.class);

        void SendImagesToScale(string Ip, string PathImage ,string Tipo, Socket iSock);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CLibrary.INSTANCE.SendImagesToScale("192.168.1.111", "C:\img.jpg", "Splash", 3306);

    }
}
```

Dll: [TransferImg.dll](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B59mJcnu1FzxdHQ5YkRTMWRXTGs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Creo que es imposible utilizando JNA, es similar a las llamadas JNI y solo soportan C y C++ la única forma que se me ocurre es vía Corba o webservice (IIS -> aplicacion java) Anexo documentación si algo te funciona
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474398/how-to-use-c-sharp-function-in-java-using-jna-lib

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario

Comment: JNA utiliza JNI, y es un subconjunto de JNI, los problemas habituales de JNA es su interfaz, únicamente es útil con binarios nativos, no con bytecodes intermedios como es el caso de C# con CIL, el segundo problema es que los nombres son iguales al de la tabla de símbolos del binario, esto incluye el [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). Deberás crear una interfaz en C o C++ sin /clr que consuma la CIL .dll , esto quiere decir que necesitarás usar [ngen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6t9t5wcf(v=vs.110).aspx) entre otras tools chained de microsoft.

Comment: hola @AngelMontesdeOca seria bueno que brindes el link de descarga de  TransferImg.dll para poder hacer la prueba de ella y asi poder responder de forma correcta a tu pregunta

Comment: @Shassain gracias por la recomendacion, edite mi pregunta.

Comment: @AngelMontesdeOca No puedes usar directamente la dll generada en c# desde JAVA, si quieres y necesitas hacerlo tienes que hacer un Wrapper en c++ que llame a la librería de c# y tu desde Java llamar a la librería generada en c++

Comment: @miguel no es tan simple, la dll generadas por c# son dlls de juguete, no sirven de nada puesto que contienen .NET assembly, el cuál aún debe compilarse ó interpretarse, se requieren de varias herramientas para poder lograr una interoperabilidad de una aplicación no asistida a una que sí lo es (asignar dll en memoria, ejecutar interprete, interpretar dll, decirle al interprete que ejecute un método en específico, parar la interpretación, volcar la memoria tras la invocación, analizar información en memoria, convertir datos a primitivos válidos, liberar memoria)

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios

Comment: Aun no he podido solucionarlo pero me ha ayudado a tener una mejor idea de lo que necesito hacer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acabo de crear un proyecto de prueba en c# y he añadido la DLL que subiste al proyecto creado.
Y al inspeccionar la dll no existe la función `int SendImagesToScale(string Ip, string PathImage ,string Tipo, Socket iSock);` como tal pero existe una parecida que es esta: `int TORREYSendImagesToScale(String sIpScale, String sPathImage, String sTypeData, Socket iSock);`

El problema es que si quieres usarla no puedes hacerlo directamente ya que esta es una función de una clase y la función no esta declarada como estática por lo que deberás crear primero una instancia de la clase y luego llamar a la función através de la instancia creada.

```
TorreyTransfer.CommandTorrey commandTorrey = new TorreyTransfer.CommandTorrey();
commandTorrey.TORREYSendImagesToScale("IpScale", "pathImage", "TypeData", "UnSocket");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es que quiero usarla desde JAVA

Comment: Igualmente aunque la uses desde java no puedes usar directamente la función, primero deberás crear una instancia de ese objecto. Es como una clase en JAVA que tiene una función, si esta no es estática no puedes usarla mientras no declares e instancies un objeto de ese tipo.

Answer (score 2):

Revise la dll y no encontre ninguna funcion `void SendImagesToScale(string Ip, string PathImage ,string Tipo, Socket iSock);` pero si hay una `int TORREYSendImagesToScale(String sIpScale, String sPathImage, String sTypeData, Socket iSock);` puede que ese sea tu error, decopile la dll con dotpeek (https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/download/) puede que asi puedas estudiar mas la dll o volver a hacerlo a tu gusto, bueno asi pude ver todo el codigo dentro del dll, en el namespace de **TorreyTransfer** se encuentra la funcion `TORREYSendImagesToScale`.

Te hice un poco de codigo que podria servirte:

```
import java.net.Socket;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class Main {

    private final static int PUERTO = 1234;
    private final static String HOST = "localhost";
    protected static Socket mysocket;

    public interface MyObject extends Library {
        //sIpScale=ip de destino de la imagen
        //sPathImage= path de la imagen a enviar
        //sTypeData=varia entre "Splash", "TestUsb","Product" y "TestSdcard"
        //iSock= socket de conexion de tu aplicacion

        int TORREYSendImagesToScale(String sIpScale, String sPathImage, String sTypeData, Socket iSock);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            mysocket = new Socket(HOST, PUERTO);
            MyObject myObj = (MyObject) Native.loadLibrary("TransferImg.dll", MyObject.class);
            int resultado = myObj.TORREYSendImagesToScale("192.168.1.111", "C:/img.jpg", "Splash", mysocket);
            //resultado = {0=correcto windows}, otros datos error
        }
    }
}
```

Donde `TransferImg.dll` debe de estar en la dirección de tu proyecto.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi pregunta, gracias por tu observacion creo que si estaba mal la primera documentacion que me pasaron, trate de replicar tu respuesta mas no he podido obtener resultado.

Comment: La verdad no se como lo estés aplicando, el valor obtenido es de 0 para mi

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas hacer varios wrappers, llamar a una clase que llame a una clase que llame a tu `DLL` en `C#`, un ejemplo es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí tienes una pagina que podría ser de gran ayuda:
[LINK](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13093/C-method-calls-within-a-Java-program)

Comment: gracias, le hechare un vistazo.